# How can I list the contents of a makeself archive without running it?

Tags: shell-script, archive

I have a makeself archive, and I want to see what it has inside, ie. which files would get extracted, rather than actually run its script part. How do I do that?

I would rather not actually extract any of it, but if that's the only way, then I'm willing to do the extraction - as long as none of the (ba)sh code in it actually runs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The generated archive has a `--list` option, which you can use to list its contents.

For reference, I'm talking about this version in Debian:

```
ii  makeself       2.2.0-1      all          utility to generate self-extractables
```

which generates this chunk in the script:

```
MS_Help()
{   
    cat << EOH >&2 
Makeself version 2.2.0 
 1) Getting help or info about $0 : 
  $0 --help   Print this message 
  $0 --info   Print embedded info : title, default target directory, embedded script ... 
  $0 --lsm    Print embedded lsm entry (or no LSM) 
  $0 --list   Print the list of files in the archive 
  $0 --check  Checks integrity of the archive 

 2) Running $0 : 
  $0 [options] [--] [additional arguments to embedded script] 
  with following options (in that order) 
  --confirm             Ask before running embedded script 
  --quiet               Do not print anything except error messages 
  --noexec              Do not run embedded script 
  --keep                Do not erase target directory after running 
                        the embedded script 
  --noprogress          Do not show the progress during the decompression 
  --nox11               Do not spawn an xterm 
  --nochown             Do not give the extracted files to the current user 
  --target dir          Extract directly to a target directory 
                        directory path can be either absolute or relative 
  --tar arg1 [arg2 ...] Access the contents of the archive through the tar command 
  --                    Following arguments will be passed to the embedded script 
EOH
}
```

Its manual page needs some work, but the script is easy enough to read - see [git repository](https://github.com/megastep/makeself)

Further reading: [makeself - Make self-extractable archives on Unix](http://stephanepeter.com/makeself/)

Comment: That executes the script, though. It doesn't execute the post-extract code **if the archive is a genuine makeself archive**, but if the archive is potentially malicious, this executes arbitrary code.

Answer (score 3):

A makeself archive consists of three parts:

1. A shell script.
2. A gzip-compressed tar archive.
3. Optionally, more data at the end.

Normally, when you run the archive, it executes the shell script, which will extract the embedded archive into a temporary directory, and then execute a specific file extracted from the archive. The script contains information about its own size and the size of the tar file, which allows it to extract the embedded tar file in the middle.

(The "more data at the end" can be anything. For GoG installers, for example, it contains a zip file with the actual game contents. Those files can be extracted with `unzip`, bypassing makeself entirely. This works because zip files use offsets relative to the end of the file.)

If you open the file with `less` on Linux, you can see the contents of the script, which tells you all you need to know. Near the top, there should be a line like:

```
filesizes="12345"
```

This tells you that the embedded tar file is 12345 bytes long. (In theory, `filesizes` could list the size of more than one file, but in practice, it seems to be rare for an archive to contain more than one file.)

If you then search for `head`, you should find a line like:

```
offset=`head -n 519 "$1" | wc -c | tr -d " "`
```

This is the logic used by the script to figure out its own size. As you can see, the script knows it's 519 lines long.

Now you know the size of the script (in lines) and the size of the embedded tar archive (in bytes), youcan list the contents of the embedded archive as follows:

```
tail +520 ~/Downloads/gog_huniepop_2.0.0.3.sh | head -c 12345 | tar tz
```

`tail +N` will list the contents of a file starting from line `N`. We use 520, which is 1 more than 519, because we want to start just *after* the end of the script (so excluding the last line).

Some notes:

- If you want to extract the files (instead of just listing them), use `tar xz` instead of `tar tz`. You probably want to do that in an empty directory!
- On BSD, tar reads from a tape device instead of stdin by default. Use `tar tzf -` in that case.

Comment: The first example should be filesizes="12345" to make it consistent with the final extract command.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was as simple as

```
makeself_archive.sh --tar xf
```

This extracted the contents of the archive into PWD.